# FCM console push test is currently broken? (Android)

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push

I've been using FCM console(web) to test push notification for Android smartphone.

I use push token from Android device, but FCM console says "Completed" and it's not delivered.

It worked fine before, but recent few days, it's not working.
Is there anyone facing same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from FCM support team.

> Thank you for that information.
>
> It would seem that you are affected by the changes made between July
>   31 and August 1st. We rolled out a change to Firebase Notifications to
>   filter apps by GMP App Id rather than by package name. This change was
>   purely internal and should have had no effect on visible behavior as
>   all apps using Firebase should have had both package name and app id
>   set to match. However, we are now seeing some apps that have the wrong
>   app id set and this is causing messages to not be delivered (or in
>   some cases to be delivered to the wrong app if an app has the app id
>   of another app). These apps have a bug that was previously masked but
>   is now exposed.
>
> We are investigating ways in which apps have sent these incorrect app
>   ids and ways in which we can catch them and warn app developers.
>
> For now, the Firebase Notifications console will only work with apps
>   that use the FCM SDK. We recommend updating to the latest version of
>   the FCM SDK in order to mitigate the issue, but in case you don't want
>   to migrate to FCM SDK, you can still use your own server to send push
>   notifications.
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused. Please let me
>   know if there's anything else I could help with.
>
> Regards,